# vb.NET Screen Location

Tags: vb.net, location, screen

I'm working with a multi monitor setup. I know that you can do Screen.AllScreens(x) to get a specific screen, but is there any way to identify which screen is in which position?

I.E.

Screen 0 is on the right, screen 1 is on the left, screen 2 is in the middle

I'm trying to position one form at the top left of each screen, and the only way i can think to do this is something like

```
Me.Location = New Point(-Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Width, Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Top)
```

(That is assuming that screen 1 is on the left)

Any help?

Wrapping it in some sort of a loop that would autogenerate the forms for each screen would be amazing too, but i can handle that myself. I just need to know how to position each one at the top left of each screen..

Thanks :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned on another site, if I'm understanding you correctly then something like this should do as you want:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim number = 1

    For Each scr In Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Bounds.Left)
        Dim f As New Form With {.Text = number.ToString(),
                                .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                                .Location = scr.Bounds.Location}

        f.Show()

        number += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at you being all thorough and answering me on both sites, Thanks a ton man. Worked perfect :) I for whatever reason didn't think to order the array by the Left position on the bounds.

Comment: "Look at you being all thorough and answering me on both sites".  Yeah, sometimes people forget where they've posted questions and check one place and not another, plus the answer might help others who might check one place and not another.  Also, it means I can get rep points in both places. ;-)